# C# - Subtracting an int by user input value

Tags: c#, .net, variables, subtraction

So I've been spending longer on this issue than I like to admit. It seems like the code below would make perfect sense, but when I get the final output of **balance** it generates a far from correct number that I still have not figured out the meaning behind. For example, *100 - 50 = 47* (according to my code).

Therefore, I'm trying to simply let the user input a number that is subtracted from balance. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
int balance = 100;

int userInput = Console.Read();

balance -= userInput;
```

Comment: change Read() to ReadLine() and convert that input into int manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Console.Read()` reads a character from the Console and will return the ASCII code of it. You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.7.2).

So if you input 50, it will read the first character: '5', and it's ASCII value is 53.

So 100 - 53 = 47.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out I spent all my time focusing on the wrong part. Didn't even consider that.

`int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

That updated code seems to have fixed it.